# Cannot AudioStream.getData() Java

Tags: java, audio

```
try
    {
    audioStream = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("Music/del.wav"));
    audioData = audioStream.getData();
    loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);
   } 
catch (IOException error)
{
    System.out.println("Couldnt locate file");
}
player.start(loop);
```

This is my current code and it failes to play music (the exception is being thrown). The specific line throwing the exception is

```
audioData = audioStream.getData();
```

I'm working in BlueJ so I manually figured this out by removing and re-adding lines.

Why would this line compile yet not work? What would prevent the getData() method working? i checked the properties of the file and its full access.

The stacktrace:

java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object

at sun.audio.AudioStream.getData(AudioStream.java:125)

at Client.main(Client.java:30)

at __SHELL1.run(__SHELL1.java:6)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)

Comment: "the exception is being thrown": which one? Stack trace please.

Comment: java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object

 at sun.audio.AudioStream.getData(AudioStream.java:125)


 at Client.main(Client.java:30)

 at __SHELL1.run(__SHELL1.java:6)

 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

 at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:730)

Comment: Replace `System.out.println("Couldnt locate file");` by `error.printStackTrace()`. Ignoring the error message and the stack trace is the best way to not know what the problem is.

Comment: Updated. Thankyou for that advice